# Predicting time with number of transactions

Tags: algorithms, linear-regression

I have a school project and I can't really figure this one out. I have a data frame of transactions (# of transactions) and time (seconds).

I have graphed this out and Y = time, X = transactions.
I have to be able to predict the time using this set of data. Is there anyway that I could do this or do I have to create my own equation for this?
I tried using Linear Regression to be able to make a prediction but the values seem very off. Now I just have no idea on what to do.

[This is the graph that I have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uLCO.png)

[Here I tried to make a linear regression model and graphed it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qvAz.png)

[information on the linear regression model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMP42.png)

[Using SHA256 - Raw Data tx = x, speed = y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaju9.png)

[Using Keccak256](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1wN3.png)

Thank you so much for anyone who will be able to help.

Comment: Consider using polynomial regression, possibly quadratic: $y = ax^2 + bx + c$. Find values for $a, b, c$ that fit the data. Or even try $y = Ab^{x}$. It could help if you provide the raw data.

Comment: thank you so much for replying! Okay i'll update it and put a raw data! Please check it out for me! Thank you again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Your *train* dataset has 12 rows of data, this is minuscule. And what are the x-values of your test dataset?

Comment: The x values are number of transactions, basically the idea is given the number of transactions it will be done at y time (speed). Do you think I should add more training data? my training data is actually from a system that I made and time how fast it makes the transactions

Comment: Much more training data. This is too small. Also you claim you have used a linear regression and that the results weren't good, but what data did you test it on?

Comment: I tested it on the same number of transactions. How big should this data be usually? It's hard to gain the training data since I get it from my system and as the numbers of transactions get higher it takes really long to finish. Note that my number of transactions are in the power of 2. Should I just do it like by 10's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just threw the raw data into Excel and got a quadratic regression formula.

The formula is $ y = (-5 \cdot 10^{-6}) x^2 + (0.1224)x + 1.3228$

Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'll check this out!! Btw, do you have any links on how I could be able to do this in excel? This looks really cool and I also want to learn about it. I also have to do this for the 2nd test on my other system. I'll update my question so you can see it too.

Comment: I have uploaded the other set of data. I'm sorry for all these questions. This is really an important part of my project and at the same time I wanna learn about it too. My school hasn't really taught this type of thing.

Comment: Just an update, I've tried the formula and when I did a test of if x = 512, I would get a y = -3184.96. Am I doing anything wrong for this to happen?

Comment: Ah sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: @RaindeCastro Check it now

Comment: @RaindeCastro about how to learn more about Excel, I don't have any links as such, but you can just play around with the thing and figure it out. Use the MS website (Microsoft) and the Help section. This specific thing is with the trendline on a graph.

Comment: Also if this answer helped you, please let me know it was useful by accepting it!

Comment: I tried it and the data seems really good!! The error doesn't seem to be that far off! Do you think if I have more data the error will be lessened?

Comment: Is there a way for me to be able to have a copy of the excel file that you've done! I also have to do this for the other system's setup and I don't wanna keep asking since I'm getting abit shy already. But seriously though, I appreciate the help. This is amazing!

Comment: Um okay do this. Copy all the time values into one column and the data into an adjacent column. Then go to charts and insert a scatter plot with curved lines. Then go to chart elements and add a trendline. Select polynomial with degree 2 as the option in the trendline.

Comment: Oh no i just noticed something, I think I have got it mixed up the X and Y, the Y axis should be the time (speed) and the X axis should be the number of transactions. Could you double check this please! I just wanna make sure. Y = something that is measured and predicted ( this is correct right? )

Comment: @RaindeCastro yes in my graph, the x axis is no. of transactions. I saw that you had a $2^x$ in your original graph, see the $2, 4, 8 \dots$, so I used the same.